# Looking and Performing action through xpath variables in Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have the following page layout:

```
<div class="x1">
    <button aria-expanded="false" class="button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">Actions<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="<my_link>/start">Start</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-target="delete" data-toggle="modal">Delete</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<my_link>/auth">Authenticate</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each one of these represent a button ("Action"), which when clicked will present a dropdown menu between `Start`, `Delete`, and `Authenticate`.
I'm trying to automate my page test from the backend using `Selenium` and `Python`.
Here what I have so far:

```
def scan_page(action):
    scan_url = urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url, "foo")
    self.driver.get(scan_url)
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='x1']")
    # loop over all the elements found by xpath
    for element in elements:
        element.click()
        ul = element.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-menu")

        if action == "scan":
           if "Start" in ul.text:
              # start the action
              button = element.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']")
              button.click()
      elif action == "delete":
           if "Delete" in ul.text:
              self.log.info("Deleting...")
     elif action == "auth":
           if "auth" in ul.text:
              self.log.info("Authenticating...")
     else:
        continue
```

The function is given an `action`, which define what is to be done. If `"start"` then loops over all the `elements` and click the `Start` option. However, it doesn't look like it's going over all the `buttons` defined in the page, and only the first `button` is being started. So, for some reason, the `Delete` option is somehow selected.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update:

I've added a JS Fiddle so people can play with that:
http://jsfiddle.net/58rs3kuk/1/

Comment: Is it an open access URL? Tricky to answer without more info...

Comment: @lambo477 it is not ... however I can give you more information as requested.

Comment: Perhaps a little bit of javascript which injects the dropdown lists so that I can try and replicate the problem?

Comment: @lambo477 hold a sec I will try to put a jsfiddle together

Comment: @lambo477 jsfiddle added to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and fixed a few issues. I think this should work or at least get you on the right track.

1) You were clicking the container `DIV` which isn't necessary. It probably doens't hurt, it just doesn't do anything productive.

2) You were clicking `BUTTON` only if `action = "scan"`. You want to click `BUTTON` for *all* actions so those lines need to move up before the `IF` starts. So... you will 1. click the `BUTTON`, 2. determine what action was requested, and 3. perform that action.

3) You were grabbing the `UL` to get the text but the text you want is in the `LI` (but is not needed after the changes I made).

4) I changed the names of some of the variables to make them more identifiable, `elements` is now `buttonContainers` and `element` is now `buttonContainer`. I would suggest you follow this practice because it will help you (and others) debug your code more easily.

5) Since we know the order of the actions in each button and they are all the same, we don't have to look for the text in the link... we can just click them by index: 0 for Start, 1 for Delete, 2 for Authenticate.

6) Added a warning in the logs if an invalid action is passed. You should probably change that to an exception or whatever is appropriate in your scripts.

7) Fixed the indent of the code you posted

```
def scan_page(action):
  scan_url = urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url, "foo")
  self.driver.get(scan_url)
  buttonContainers = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='x1']")
  # loop over all the buttonContainers
  for buttonContainer in buttonContainers:
    buttonContainer.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
    lis = buttonContainer.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    if action == "start":
      lis[0].click() # because we know the order of the actions and they are the same in each button, we can just click on them by index.
      self.log.info("Starting...")
    elif action == "delete":
      lis[1].click()
      self.log.info("Deleting...")
    elif action == "auth":
      lis[2].click()
      self.log.info("Authenticating...")
    else:
      self.log.info("WARNING: " + action + " is not a valid action.")
      continue
```